# Need barcode reader for my own app?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for i-phone 4 and i-pad-2, in which i need to read bar-code to compare prices different site like e bay or amazon, I listened about z bar(open source) bar code reader i read its description in app store, but i can't find that does it support i-pad-2? One thing more i need to ask do you have tutorial link to call z bar API to communicate with my application?
If someone give me any better option except z bar, but it should be open source and not external like pic2Shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little googling dont hurt though.. Here is a open source zbar code.
[twotoasters](https://github.com/twotoasters/zbar)

Here is an sdk with tutorial on their site..
[zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html)

Hope it helps you..

Comment: tnx bro, I am following this tut, just tell me that Zbar support ipad2 or not?

Comment: btw bro.. if it helped u please will u accept the answer.. Thanks.

Comment: raised your point. and sorry bro cant help you with the second one as i have not tried it yet.